# Characterization of Riesz sequences

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set.
Show that $\mathcal{E} = \{e^{int}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a Riesz sequence in $L^2(X)$ if and only if $X+2\pi \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R}$.

We say that $\mathcal{E}$ is a Riesz sequence in $L^2(X)$ if we have the following chain of inequalities: $$A \sum_n |c_n|^2 \leq \left\|\sum_n c_n e^{int}\right\|_{L^2(X)}^2 \leq B \sum|c_n|^2,$$ where $c = (c_n)$ is a finite sequence.

Suppose that $X+2\pi\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R}$. Then since $X$ is bounded there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X \subseteq [-\pi N, \pi N]$. With this we get the the latter inequality by using the fact that $\mathcal{E}$ forms an orthogonal basis in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ and the periodicity of its elements. However I am unsure how to achieve the fitst inequality. One idea I had (which may be wrong) is to cover the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ by a finite number of translates of the form $\{X+2\pi k\}_{k=1}^N$. However, I cannot convince myself that I can do this only using a finite number of translates. If this is true, then this direction is done. Otherwise, I am unsure. As for the other direction, I have no clue on how to start. Of course one only needs to show that every real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ can be written in the form $r = x+2\pi m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This question is best visualized in the circle,  so let me first reduce it to that situation.

Let us therefore consider the projection $q$ from ${\mathbb R}$ to $S^1$ given by
$$
  q:t\in {\mathbb R}\mapsto e^{it}\in S^1,
  $$
and let us put $Z=q(X)$.  The condition that $X+2\pi \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R}$ is therefore clearly equivalent to $Z=S^1$.

On the other hand,  in order to rephrase the Riesz condition, I claim that the following are equivalent:

1. (The stated Riesz condition on ${\mathbb R}$).
   There exist positive real numbers $A$ and $B$ such that, for all sequences of complex numbers $\{c_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$, with
   finitely many nonzero terms, one has that
   $$
     A \sum_n|c_n|^2 \leq \underbrace{\Big\|\sum_n c_n e^{int}\Big\|_{L^2(X)}^2}_{I_1} \leq B \sum_n|c_n|^2. \tag {$*$}
     $$
2. (The Riesz condition on $S^1$).
   There exist positive real numbers $A$ and $B$ such that, for all sequences of complex numbers $\{c_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$, with
   finitely many nonzero terms, one has that
   $$
     A \sum_n|c_n|^2 \leq \underbrace {\Big\|\sum_n c_n z^n\Big\|_{L^2(Z)}^2}_{I_2} \leq B \sum_n|c_n|^2, \tag {$**$}
     $$
   where $z^n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ function in the standard orthonormal basis for $L^2(S^1)$, namely   $z\mapsto z^n$.

In order to prove that (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2),  and putting
$$
  X_n=X\cap [2\pi n, 2\pi (n+1)),
  $$
observe that
$
  X=\bigcup_{n=-N}^N X_n,
  $
for some $N$.

So if we are given $\{c_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$, as above, and we set $f(z)=\sum_n c_n z^n$, we have
$$
  \Big\|\sum_n c_n e^{int}\Big\|_{L^2(X)}^2 =
  \frac 1{2\pi }\int_X|f(e^{it})|^2\,dt= $$$$=
  \frac 1{2\pi }\sum_{n=-N}^N \int_{X_n} |f(e^{it})|^2\,dt=
  \sum_{n=-N}^N \int_{q(X_n)} |f(z)|^2\,dz,
  $$
where the last integral is taken with respect to the normalized Haar measure on the circle.

Regarding the last term displayed above, and  noticing that  $Z=\bigcup_{n=-N}^N q(X_n)$, (incidentally no longer a disjoint union),  we have
$$
  \int_{Z} |f(z)|^2\,dz \leq
  \sum_{n=-N}^N \int_{q(X_n)} |f(z)|^2\,dz \leq  $$$$ \leq
  \sum_{n=-N}^N \int_{Z} |f(z)|^2\,dz =
  (2N+1) \int_{Z} |f(z)|^2\,dz.
  $$

Summarizing,  if we denote the middle term in ($*$) by $I_1$, and the middle term in ($**$) by $I_2$, we have shown
that
$$
  I_2\leq I_1\leq   (2N+1)I_2.
  $$
This said it is now clear that (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2).

(EDIT: The remaining part of this answer was reformulated,  as follows.)

With the appropriate translations provided by the work done so far, the equivalent "circle version" of the present question becomes:

**Theorem**. If $Z\subseteq S^1$ is a closed subset, then the following are equivalent:

- $Z=S^1$,
- (2) holds.

*Proof*. The forward implication clearly follows from Parseval's identity (with $A=B=1$).  For the reverse direction, consider the
orthogonal projection $P$ from $L^2(S^1)$ to $L^2(Z)$, namely the map
$$
  P: f \mapsto  f1_Z,
  $$
where $1_Z$ is the characteristic function of $Z$.  Given a
sequence of complex numbers $\{c_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ with
finitely many nonzero terms, let $f$ be the function on the circle given by
$$
  f(z)=\sum_n  c_nz^n,
  $$
and observe that
$$
  \|f\|_{L^2(S^1)}^2 =  \sum_n|c_n|^2,
  $$
while
$$
  \|P(f)\|_{L^2(S^1)}^2 = \|f\|_{L^2(Z)}^2 =   \Big\|\sum_n c_n z^n\Big\|_{L^2(Z)}^2.
  $$
Therefore we deduce from (2)  that
$$
  A   \|f\|^2 \leq    \|P(f)\|^2 \leq    B   \|f\|^2,  \tag {$\dagger$}
  $$
where all norms are from $L^2(S^1)$.  Observing that the functions $f$ so far considered form a  dense subspace of
$L^2(S^1)$,  we conclude that $(\dagger$) holds for every $f$ in  $L^2(S^1)$.

In particular we see that  $P$ is one-to-one.  On the other hand,  the kernel of a projection is known to be the
space orthogonal to its range, whence
$$
  \{0\} = \text{Ker}(P) = L^2(Z)^\perp = L^2(S^1\setminus Z).
  $$
So necessarily  $S^1\setminus Z$ has measure zero, but since this is an open set, we deduce that
$S^1\setminus Z$ is empty,  and hence $Z=S^1$,  as desired.  QED